# How to use firebase as an Rest API auth mechanism (with using client SDKs)?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am just making a REST API service (and behind the scenes, use Firebase DB as my DB). And to authenticate my API, I thought I could use Firebase Auth.

- Create /signUp or /signIn  --> Returns token
- Use this token to auth all other APIs

But, I am not able to find how to do this with firebase. Most solutions talk about CustomTokens & IDtokens and require a "client Side Firebase SDK". Which means, on the client side, I directly authenticate with firebase which I don't want to do.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the admin sdk to generate ID tokens to return to the client or use them internally through what means you desire. Just ensure you have verified and validated your users prior since the process only requires the users UID to generate a new one.

```js
const uid = 'some-uid';

admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

Comment: But here, the client will have to use ClientSDK and verify customToken on the client side. My idea is abstract Firebase on the client side.

Comment: that is not needed on the client. it's only used to verify further requests - if you need to decode information such as custom claims and other user data, you can create an API to decode it server-side (risky) or try decoding it on the client with a JWT decoder https://jwt.io/

Comment: But this token has a short life. This is not like an authToken, the token expires in like 1 horr. So, for every session I will have to login on the client side again and retreive a new CustomToken right?

Comment: Correct, else your clients can be spoofed if that key would be leaked, I have heard you can set it to never expire but I do not recommend this for several reasons. all you need to do is request and reverify the user every 1 hour, this is fairly standard for most REST API services.